# Craig's Interpolation Theorem in Propositional logic.

Tags: logic

This is an exercise in Mendelson's Mathematical Logic.

If $\mathscr{B} \implies \mathscr{D}$ is a tautology, and $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ have the statement letters $B_1, \dots, B_n$ in common, then there is a statement form $\mathscr{C}$ having only $B_1, \dots, B_n$ such that $\mathscr{B} \implies \mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{C} \implies \mathscr{D}$ are tautologies.

Is $B_1, \dots, B_n$ supposed to be precisely all the statements letters $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ have in common or just some of the ones they have in common (but perhaps not all of them)?

Comment: Every statement letter ${\mathscr B}$ and ${\mathscr D}$ have in common should occurr among the $B_i$. For assume you pick no $B_i$ at all, i.e. $n=0$. Then, up to equivalence you can only choose between ${\mathscr C}=0$ or ${\mathscr C}=1$, which both do not fulfill the requirement that ${\mathscr B}\Rightarrow{\mathscr C}$ and ${\mathscr C}\Rightarrow{\mathscr D}$ are tautologies if neither $\neg\ {\mathscr B}$ nor ${\mathscr C}$ are such.

Comment: Mendelson definitely means that the $B_1, \ldots, B_n$ lists all the statement letters that $\cal B$ and $\cal D$ have in common. $\cal C$ need not contain all the $B_i$, but you could arrange that if you wanted by adding trivial conjuncts $B_i \Leftrightarrow B_i$ to $\cal C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mendelson means that $B_1, \ldots, B_n$ are all the shared letters.

An interpolant, $\mathscr C$, *may* have all the shared letters in it, or just some of them.

For example, consider 
$$(A \land (B \lor \lnot B)\land D) \Rightarrow (A \lor (B \land C))$$

One interpolant here is $\mathscr C \equiv A$. Another is $A \land (B \lor \lnot B)$.

The interpolant you are likely to construct in the proof, however, will probably include all the shared letters.